# How to retrieve a user's shared resources?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

For administrative purpose, especially the deprovisioning process, it'll be useful to know if a user has shared any of his resources (Docs, files etc.) with other users.

Any tips or code that could solve this task?.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what permissions are given to users toward a file by using this [`drive.permissions.list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list) request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{fileId}/permissions
```

The response gives you information about what users are authorized to interact with the file, including  user's `id`, `name`, `role`, `type` ... that you can choose to store in your database.

You can test this by using [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/drive/v2/drive.permissions.list)

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that a fetch against the API is needed for every resource whether it is shared or not. It'll be nice to preselect the shared resources and then get the permissions.